# How to manage the Authentication screens?

Tags: react-native

I have 7 screens and I am using the redux in Navigation container I did like that if

{Token===null then show 1,2,and 3rd screens else show if token get data then show 4,5,6,7 screens} my question is if the user remove application from the recent from the 6th screen.I want if the user close application from 6th screen then user should get the 6th screens. But according to my logic token has a data now and it will start from the 4th screen. Please help me what I can I do?

Comment: you can create one variable and save it to async storage. Not sure it will work but seems like it should

Comment: Can I do like this if the user close the application from any page then if the user come back user should get that page from which page user closed last?

Answer (score -1):

You can create a hashMap for storing the user's current screen and save it in asyncStorage. Later when the user reopens the application you can fetch the data and check on which screen the user was present. Then you can navigate to that screen

Comment: Good story, now the solution...